# Windows 10 upgrade is stuck at 31%

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 (yes, I know it is pretty late to do it, but I had my reasons - most of them are related to laziness). So I have found many sites claiming that the upgrade is still officially available from Microsoft, although they do not publish it too much. I have downloaded the Windows 10 installation tool from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 , hit the "Upgrade this PC now" button and waited. At some point, the setup finally started to work with nice percentage, but it was stuck at 31% for more than 2 hours.

What I have already tried to do - with no luck, still hangs at 31%:

- Restart of setup
- Restart of the PC
- Disconnected external USB drive
- Disconnected the second monitor
- Disconnected all USB devices (keyboard, mouse)

**The question** is - where should I look to solve this problem? Maybe the upgrade process has some kind of trace/log file?

Comment: One explanation is that you don't have enough disk space. For some [people](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ic5ta4/windows_10_installer_stuck_at_31/) it was a driver problem.

Comment: Run the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant and make sure your computer is Windows 10 compliant.    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-update-assistant-3550dfb2-a015-7765-12ea-fba2ac36fb3f

Comment: See this page>>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors

Comment: 31% is almost always a driver issue. Here is one example>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-20h2#417msgdesc

Answer (score 13):

Finally got it resolved.
The log file is here `c:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log`

The last line in this log was about Conexant Audio driver.

```
Info                  MIG    AddDriverFiles: Processing device: 4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318
Info                  MIG    AddDriverFiles: Processing driver: Conexant SmartAudio HD, Conexant, Conexant
Info                  MIG    AddInfAndCatalog: Adding catalog file: C:\Windows\system32\catroot\{f750e6c3-38ee-11d1-85e5-00c04fc295ee}\oem55.cat
```

I have fully uninstalled it, rerun the upgrade and it finished without any problems.

More to read:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files

Comment: The blocker was Sennheiser Communication Audio on my end.

Comment: I was trying to upgrade from version 1909 to version 21H2 and had the same problem. For me too the blocker was Conexant Audio. I had to remove its driver and restart setup immediatly without rebooting, because on restart the driver was automatically reinstalled.

Comment: It always seems to be connected to audio drivers. In my case it was two of them: Conexant and HP Audio Dock.

Comment: It is sufficient to uninstall the drivers without deleting them from disk. You only have to make sure that you do NOT restart after uninstalling the driver in device manager. A restart would reinstall the driver automatically. Simply uninstall the driver and then start the Win setup without rebooting.

Comment: If @Jpsy's suggesting doesn't work, [here are instructions](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1252855-how-to-completely-uninstall-the-conexant-audio-driver-from-windows-10-and-unlock-the-may-2020-update/) on how to uninstall the Conexant driver completely.

Comment: @bN_ doing the exact same thing on a laptop I haven't used in a year now.  After failing both the windows update route (hanged), and the windows 10 update assistant route (chilled at 99% for half a day), AND now the recommended workaround of both of those (basically windows reinstalation) hanging at 31%, your comment has given me hope that there is indeed a way out... Really is absurd that microsoft has borked such basic features as security/system updates so badly that it requires this arcane s**t that 99% of users are not going to be able to handle...

Answer (score 3):

So - this is kind of interesting. Today, I decided to upgrade to Windows 11 (even though my laptop from 2016 has a CPU that falls just outside the approved window - haha). And I got stuck at exactly 31% in the update process, which prompted me to google the issue which quickly led me here. And even if the thread here was for a Windows 10 upgrade (from Windows 7), I figured it couldn't hurt to try the proposed solution.

I cancelled the upgrade, uninstalled both Conexant drivers (for speakers and micropone), and restarted the upgrade process. And YES - it worked perfectly. No more being stuck - it chewed right through the upgrade, and now I'm on Windows 11!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For those still struggling with this even after removing Conexant drivers: In my case there were also HP Dock Audio drivers that had to be uninstalled. First remove "HP Dock Audio" from Control Panel>Programs and Features if present, then ensure it's gone from the device manager, even if it's not visible: Open Administrator Command Prompt, type `Set devmgr show_nonpresent_devices=1` hit Enter, type `devmgmt.msc` then hit Enter. After the Device Manager opens, from the View menu, select "Show Hidden Devices", expand Sound, Video and Game Controllers, then make sure all Conexant and HP Dock Audio drivers are uninstalled via right-click Uninstall.